# NSFetchedResultsController numberOfObjects returns additional (duplicate) when run on device

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have implemented a UITableView with the NSFetchedResultsController to load data from an sqllite database.  I downloaded the database from the device to the simulator, so it is the same for both.

I observe the strange behavior that, when run on the simulator, the tableview is populated with the correct number of cells (in the initial base-case: one cell);  however when I run the same code on the device, numberOfObjects returns 2, and the tableview displays two (identical/repeated) cells.

When I inspect the sqllite file there is indeed just 1 object/row in it...

I followed the example code for my implementation and am not doing anything special.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSInteger count = [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];

    if (count == 0) {
        count = 1;
    }

    return count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger numberOfRows = 0;

    if ([[fetchedResultsController sections] count] > 0) {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
        numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
    }

    NSLog(@"SwoopListTableViewController::numberOfRowsInSection - numberOfRows:%d", numberOfRows);
    return numberOfRows;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Dequeue or if necessary create a SwoopTableViewCell, then set its Swoop to the Swoop for the current row.            
    static NSString *SwoopCellIdentifier = @"SwoopCellIdentifier";

    SwoopTableViewCell *SwoopCell = (SwoopTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SwoopCellIdentifier];
    if (SwoopCell == nil) {
        SwoopCell = [[[SwoopTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SwoopCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        SwoopCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [self configureCell:SwoopCell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return SwoopCell;
}
```

and

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    // Set up the fetched results controller if needed.
    NSLog(@"SwoopListTableViewController::fetchedResultsController - started");

    if (fetchedResultsController == nil) {

        if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
        { 
            managedObjectContext = [(SwoopAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
            NSLog(@"SwoopListTableViewController::fetchedResultsController - set managedObjectContext");
        }

        // Create the fetch request for the entity.
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Swoop" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        [aFetchedResultsController release];
        [fetchRequest release];
        [sortDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptors release];
    }

    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I'm puzzled why the same code & same database would exhibit different behavior on the simulator (works as expected) vs. the device (3GS - duplicate table cells displayed).  Can anyone help / explain / lend some insight as to what I should be looking at?

Many thanks,
Eric

** ***EDIT 1:*** **  I have done a bit more debugging into NSCoreData and NSFetchedResultsController.   It seems that the fetchRequest is indeed returning a duplicate objects from the managedContext.  Here is a the code and the corresponding console output:

Controller Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }       
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"SwoopListTableViewController::viewDidLoad - sectionInfo objects:%@", [sectionInfo objects] );        
}
```

Console Output:

```
2011-05-14 17:54:53.388 Swoop[1471:307] SwoopListTableViewController::viewDidLoad - sectionInfo objects:(
    "<Swoop: 0x187d60> (entity: Swoop; id: 0x186480 <x-coredata://A9FF2CC0-77EE-4EFF-A3A6-5F085AA9CCAC/Swoop/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Swoop: 0x187d60> (entity: Swoop; id: 0x186480 <x-coredata://A9FF2CC0-77EE-4EFF-A3A6-5F085AA9CCAC/Swoop/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Swoop: 0x188180> (entity: Swoop; id: 0x143a60 <x-coredata://A9FF2CC0-77EE-4EFF-A3A6-5F085AA9CCAC/Swoop/p1> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

I find it strange that the first two objects in sectionInfo both have the same memory address "0x187d60" and both have the same x-coredata 'path':  "//A9FF2CC0-77EE-4EFF-A3A6-5F085AA9CCAC/Swoop/p2"...   can someone explain what this means, or what might be going on?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more reading and digging around with NSCoreData, it seems the issue is due to a peculiarity of how memory is managed on the device (I would have assumed the same memory constraints/management would be applied to the simulator, but I guess there are differences between the two) -- specifically, if a view is unloaded on a low-memory warning, a fetch will be performed when the view is once again reloaded, which results in possible duplicate entries.

I found that the problem/solution described at the following link solves the problem I was experiencing:

[Duplicate NSManagedObject with NSFetchedResultsController](http://blog.engledew.com/post/560601132/duplicate-nsmanagedobject-with)

On another note, it was also helpful to learn about being able to enable different levels of NSCoreData logging by passing this argument to the application:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

Read more here:

From the Apple Developer library, see "Troubleshooting Core Data:  [Debugging Fetching](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW21) "

To add an argument via xcode, see "Supplying Launch Arguments for Command-Line Programs" on this page http://www.meandmark.com/xcodetips.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been busy on (SQLite3-)databases as well. Have you tried cleaning the device (using Product -> Clean, while iOS Device selected to run on)? When building and running, if there is a database existing, it won't get renewed... So, you might be using an old database!

---

A second thing programmers tend to forget, is that the database in your bundle isn't editable! So first, you have to copy your database from your bundle (the list of the items on the left in Xcode) to a path on your device/simulator.

```
NSError *error;
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite3"];
NSString *writableDBPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fdatabase.sqlite3"];
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL succes = [filemgr fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

if (!succes)
{
    //writable database does not exist, so copy default nonwritable from bundle
    succes = [filemgr copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"Database file copied from bundle to %@", dbPath);
    if (!succes) 
        NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    //return NO;
}

databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", writableDBPath];
```

I created two paths here. The first is your `defaultPath`. This is the one you should have included in your project. The one included in your project isn't editable, so I created the `writableDBPath`. The rest of the code is explained in comments, so it should be self-explaining, but write me back if it isn't.

Comment: @Joetah, I have been using 'clean' periodically, but even if the database is an old one, it would still identical to the one the simulator is using (as I copy the db from device->sim before running the test on sim).  I just don't get why "same code/same data" would result in different behavior in device vs. sim....

Comment: @econstantin: May be a silly question, but how do you copy the db from device to sim? Don't you just include the database in the project? That way, your database is always stored in the documents directory (both on sim and device)

Comment: @econstantin: Hey, I'm going to edit my answer now. I'd like you to try it out, it's a common problem but often forgotten!

Comment: @Joetjah - thanks very much for your time & suggestion, your point to copy files from the bundle to a writeable directory is definitely essential; however, I don't think this is where the problem is coming from in this particular case.  I'm starting off with a blank database, and doing the standard NSCoreData initializations, which creates a writeable sqllite file in the (writeable) app Documents directory.

Comment: The issue I'm experience is that there is only 1 entry in the sqllite database, however the UITableview is rendering 2 entries in the table.  For some reason, the call to {numberOfRows = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];} is returning '2' instead of '1'  (and only when run on the device!  sim works fine).   As the UITableview/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo code are in UIKit/CodeData framework libraries, I don't know how to debug into them (their methods are displayed as assembly code) to see why they would think there are two objects to render.  Anyone ?

Comment: @Joetjah - to answer your question: "how do you copy the db from device to sim?" In Xcode, go to menu Window->Organizer;  then click on your connected device - in the main window area, you should see a list of the applications installed on the device.  Click on the triangle to the left your application to expand it -- you should then see "Application Data".  Then click on the down-facing arrow to the right of "Application Data" to download the files to your local disk.  You can then browser to them via finder, or some other sqllite tool.